# "Our mind liking" or "our mind's liking"?

Tags: grammar, difference

Tell me please whiche sentence is correct.

> Our **mind** liking to reduce most of what we have been through to headings than to full stories is not a very good thing.
>
> Our **mind's** liking to reduce most of what we have been through to headings than to full stories is not a very good thing.

I feel both might be correct, if I am right, then what is the difference between *mind* *liking* and *mind's* *liking*?

Comment: **through** not **throuh**

Comment: **reduce ... to headings ... (rather) than to full stories....**   needs **rather**  when **liking** is the verb.   Also, you cannot **reduce** something to a **full** story.

Comment: Source of the examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither sentence makes sense in English.

```
The fact that our minds reduce our experiences to headings instead of full stories is a bad thing.
```

This is a better way to write this sentence because our minds don't have feelings and thus they wouldn't "like" something.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the sentence doesn't make very clear sense. But we cannot reduce something to a *full* story.

Comment: Anyway, if not to take into account that te sentence is incorrect,  which option would be correct my mind's liking or my mind liking?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope As Amanda Maring says, neither expression makes sense. The whole sentence needs rethinking.